# i want to display and save in db gender like "Female" as its value is "female" from radio button but its displaying different value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display gender as its value from radio button but its getting the whole view

Here is the view:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class=" col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Gender<font color="red">*</font></label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, new { @type = "radio", @name = "Male", value = "Male" })Male
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, new { @type = "radio", @name = "Female", @value = "Female" })Female
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, new { @type = "radio", @name = "Other", @value = "Other" }) Other
    </div>
</div>
```

[it is save in database like this i want only Gender Value like "Female"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Uzi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Second argument for the radio button is the Value for it. Please refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.RadioButtonFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Object,System.Object%29) for the documentation. But you are passing the htmlAttributes instead of the Value, That is why you are getting the htmlAttributes inserted in DB.

Use like this.

```
<label for="inputEmail1" class=" col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Gender<font color="red">*</font></label>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Male") Male
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Female") Female
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Other") Other
</div>
```

Also, you don't need to specify `@type="radio"` because the HTML Helper method `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` will render `<input type="radio" />` by default.

As @Stephen Muecke mentioned in the comment, You don't need to specify @name attribute as well.

Comment: You also need to remove the pointless `new { @name = "Male" }` etc (never attempt to set the `name` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` - and fortunately its ignored anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "Male", new { @checked = true }) 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.gender, "Female", new { @checked = true })
```